# Passing data from DOM to scope not working angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm killing myself on one thing : I'm trying to pass an object from the DOM to my controller. In this object, there is an array of objects which contains n values. But when I got it in my scope function, it said that the array is composed of 1 object.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-if="statePage == 'listeProducts' && listProducts != null"  ng-repeat="product in listProducts" class="product_item"  ng-mouseenter="negativeInformation(product)" ng-mouseleave="normalInformation(product)" ng-click="showProductDetails(product, product.size)" ng-class="{'br': $index % 2 == 0}"> 

..Doing my stuff...

</div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.showProductDetails = function(product, sizes) {
console.log(sizes); 
}
```

Even my browser's console shows me strange stuff ..

[image]

Any idea ?

**EDIT** : this is a console.log of my listProducts :

[image]

Comment: You should post more about your code, when and where does that $scope function called? What are other model variables and function calls etc.

You should provide us with minimal-working example

Comment: What you mean "trying to pass an object from the DOM"? Anyhow, controller does all the manipulations. You can't add/remove items into array or object by only two way data binding.

Comment: @SergeyGoliney trying is doing whihout sucess.. I know that, that's why I'm confused. Can it be related to too many conditions on the ng-repeat ?

Comment: Could you post the structure of product object?

Comment: is it `product.size` or `product.sizes`?

Comment: @Akis product contains the object size which contains the array sizes

Comment: To debug I'd do {{ product.size }} inside the div to see what that looks like in the DOM

Comment: product.size.sizes? I am not sure why you made the structure of product like this.

Comment: @gmustudent I did your suggestion, the object in the DOM is correct (size contains the array of 4 objects), and in my scope function, only one

Comment: @HamidSardar Because there are product with different sizes, and others with unique sizes, which doesnt have the sizes array

Comment: @Jibeee Next thing I'd try while debugging is keeping the {{}} and removing all other directives from the product except for the ngRepeat and the ngClick. Maybe some kinda trippy directive clashing might be goin on!? Cool problem tho lemme know how that works out!

Comment: @gmustudent It isn't cool ahah I'm on it for hours and I don't know what to do.. Removing others directive hasn't effect btw.

Comment: @Jibeee okay Let's assume that there are two kinds of objects, i.e. one that has only one size, the other that has different sizes. Makes sense?
If so, how are you going to output of the console.log(sizes) in two cases?

Comment: @HamidSardar This is for illustrating the problem, I do tests afterwards to see if there are sizes or not.

Comment: can you try `ng-click="showProductDetails(listProducts[$index], listProducts[$index].size)"`?

Comment: also try to console.log like this `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sizes)));`

Comment: Can you even use ng-if and ng-repeat on the same element in angular?  That just seems so wrong to me...